# css: dir="rtl" VS style="direction:rtl"

Tags: css, direction

I know how to style when the direction is inline

```
<div dir="rtl">foo</div>

div[dir="rtl"]
{
 ....;
}
```

But **how to style**

```
<div style="direction:rtl">foo</div> ?
```

Both behaves as expected (right "alignment" of text) but I need finer tweaking for some elements inside (float, text-align...) and I can't set up my rule correctly in the second case.

**I can't edit the html. I MUST use style="direction:rtl".**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you can't modify the HTML, a really really hacky selector would be:

```css
div[style*="direction:rtl"] {
    ...
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XPDcH/1).

Note that I'm using `style*=` as opposed to just `style=` as this will also match elements which have more than just `direction:rtl` declared within the element's `style` property.

For extra strength in the selector, you could also use `[style*="direction: rtl"]` to handle `style` attributes which separate the values from the properties with a space:

```css
[style*="direction:rtl"], [style*="direction: rtl"] { ... }
```

Alternatively in this case you could just match on a `style` attribute which contains "rtl", as I'm pretty sure this combination of characters isn't used in any other property (ignoring external resources like background image file names):

```css
[style*="rtl"] { ... }
```

[**Updated JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XPDcH/2/).

Comment: Or if that div is for example the fifth div, you could use `div:nth-child(5) { ... }`.

Comment: 1+ You could also use `div[style~="direction:rtl"]` which will work in instances like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5tS8u/ .. "represents an attr whose value is a whitespace-separated list" .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: @JoshCrozier `*=` is a better selector as the selector may not be separated with white space (for instance, it may end in a `;` (this breaks your JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5tS8u/1/)).

Comment: +1 However what if it looks like `direction: rtl`? :)

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yep, you're right - I added that comment when your answer was still [style=".."]

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Alternatively you could do `div[style*="direction"][style*="rtl"]` with multiple attr selectors. Here is a **[demo](http://jsbin.com/wunusuga/1/edit)**

Comment: @HashemQolami sure, but you could still have a direction of `ltr` and a background image which has `rtl` in the path, for instance.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly:  just as your solution breaks if there's a comment that contains /*direction :rtl*/. Just kidding. Your solution was a life-saver and your jsfiddle was really appreciated. Thank you. PS: for your information in my special case direction was spelled DIRECTION (sharepoint sucks)

Answer (score 32):

Use **dir="auto"** on forms and inserted text in order to automatically detect the direction of content supplied at run-time

```html
<div dir="auto">Hello, world!</div>
<br/>
<div dir="auto">لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله</div>
<br/>
<input type="text" dir="auto" value="Hello, world!" > 
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" dir="auto" value="لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله" >
```

JSFIDDLE Demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/80k0drsf/

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suppose because I stated that I don't have access to html.

Comment: sometimes you want different direction, regardless of the content's language, so you don't want the browser to decide.

Answer (score -4):

just add class "rtl" to html tag

```
<html dir="rtl" class="rtl">
 <head>
   <style>
      html[class*="rtl"] body {
         background-color:blue;
      }
      html[class*="rtl"] div{
         background-color:green;
      }
   </style>
 </haed>

 <body>

 <div>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but it won't fit because I don't have access to html