# Style only elements with `direction: rtl`

Tags: html, css

Let's suppose I have a problem like the one below. Is there is any way to select using CSS only, only the elements with the `direction: rtl` style? Thanks in advance!

```css
.rightToLeft {
  direction: rtl;
}

.leftToRight {
  direction: ltr;
}

/* Is there is any simple way to select all of the 3 different spans with the dirction=rtl property? */
```

```html
<span class="rightToLeft">This is RtL, </span>
<span class="letfToRight">and this is LtR!</span> (: <br/>

<span dir="rtl">This is RtL too,</span>
<span style="direction: rtl;">and this one also! </span>
```

I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511460/css-dir-rtl-vs-style-directionrtl), but it only works when the given property is given inside the element, and not via the CSS class (first two examples).

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 rules: for class, attribute and attribute content.

```css
.rightToLeft {
  direction: rtl;
}

.leftToRight {
  direction: ltr;
}

.rightToLeft, *[dir='rtl'], *[style*='direction: rtl']{
  color: green;
}

/* Is there is any simple way to select all of the 3 different spans with the dirction=rtl property? */
```

```html
<span class="rightToLeft">This is RtL, </span>
<span class="letfToRight">and this is LtR!</span> (: <br/>

<span dir="rtl">This is RtL too,</span>
<span style="direction: rtl;">and this one also! </span>
```

Comment: I'm searching for a way to select the class "rightToLeft" without actually using it (just by searching for the direction property). Is this possible?

Comment: You can use just `*[dir='rtl'], *[style*='direction: rtl']{ ... }` to select elements without using class names. What is your intention selecting this elements?  Any of these properties does not cover setting the style via javascript (`element.style.direction='rtl'`). In this case you must use javascript `getComputedStyle()` to get the current rendered style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use comma separator selector:

```
  .right-to-left, *[style*="direction:rtl"], *[dir="rtl"]{
        //your style...
    }
```

> I changed **rightToLeft** to **right-to-left**. for naming convention in CSS classes.